# transforming exponential distribution to uniform

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

The question is to find a function that transforms a random variable $X$ that has an exponential distribution given by parameter $\lambda = 1$ such that the function applied to $X$ has a uniform distribution over the interval $[3, 5]$. I'm familiar with transforming variables to the standard uniform distribution, but the modified range is throwing me off. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a uniform $U$ on the interval $[0,1]$,
$$
2U+3
$$
is uniform on $[3,5]$.

Comment: Oh, I see. So just compose this function with the function used to transform $X$ to $U$ (given by $1 - e^{-X}$) ie. $2(1 - e^{-X}) + 3$?